# Magento 1.9 - Override layout to display Custom Attribute on Cart Page (RWD Theme)

Tags: magento-1.9, rwd

I am trying to display custom attribute on cart page below `SKU` field. I managed to do it using below code at this location `app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/checkout/cart/item`

```
<div class="product-cart-sku">
  <span class="label"><?php echo $this->__('Points'); ?>:</span> <?php echo $_item->getProduct()->getData('customer_product_points'); ?>
</div>
```

Placing `default.phtml` at location `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/namespace/modulename/checkout/cart/item` is not working.

How do I override default layout in order to display my custom attribute ? Currently it fetches `rwd` package. I do not intend to change the package, but if my module is installed, it will call my `item/default.phtml` and display attribute.

Tried using below code in my layout xml but not does not seem to be working.

```
<checkout_cart_index>
  <reference name ="checkout.cart">
        <block type="checkout/cart" name="checkout.cart">
                <action method="addItemRender">
                    <type>simple</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer</block><template>ei/productpoint/checkout/cart/item/default.phtml</template>
                </action>
            </block>
        </reference>
    </checkout_cart_index>
```

**P.S.** It should work for all types of products

Comment: In all types of products default.phtml file is called same location. Only change block

Comment: Okay, but how can I display my custom `default.phtml` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This this

```
<checkout_cart_index>
        <reference name="checkout.cart">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>{your_namespace}/{your_modulename}/checkout/car‌​t/item/default.phtml</template></action>
        </reference>
</checkout_cart_index>
```

Comment: This will call my `default.phtml` file ? And if yes, how do I get product object ?

Comment: yes your default.phtml

Comment: your default.phtml at location app/design/frontend/rwd/ei/productpoint/checkout/cart/item/ right?

Comment: No it will be under my custom module i.e. `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/mynamespace/mymodulename/checkout/cart/item/default.phtml`. Also putting above code it says `Fatal error: Call to a member function getProduct() on a non-object`

Comment: updates ans check now

Comment: I have already mentioned that in my xml but fatal error `Fatal error: Call to a member function getProduct() on a non-object`

Comment: updated ans check now